# Node.JS TCP Server Encryption Layer

Tags: encryption, tcp, binary, stream, node.js

Does Node.JS support sending binary data? or does it require a Base64 layer?

Also, how best would I create an encryption layer? I am expecting I will create a module that acts exactly like the net module (as it pertains to tcp client/server communication) and then just call an underlying net module.

However, I would like the encryption layer to be easily added to a file I/O stream. Would those two operations have to work different?

I know little about Node.JS but I know Java and browser based JavaScript very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Node.js supports binary data.

For encrypted communication it has [built-in support](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/tls.html) for SSL / TLS.

Comment: The encryption routine we are using is proprietary and does not yet exist in Node.JS (or JavaScript for that matter). I think that I can get some foundation on the design out of [`tls.js` source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/tls.js).